# Not being able to extract all the requirements of each job

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, screen-scraping

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNQuv.png)Hi I am trying to do a web scraping using python, I want to extract the job title, company name, salary and skills required. I managed to get all the information I wanted except one thing which is skills required. Nir Elbaz helped me to partially solve this problem but for some reason I only get the first skill required for each job description. Here is my code as well as a screenshot of the results I got.

```
import pandas as pd 
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv 
from itertools import zip_longest 
job_title = []
company_name = []
location = []
salary = []
links = []
skills = []
page_number = 0

while True: 
    result = requests.get(f"https://www.reed.co.uk/jobs/data-analyst-jobs?pageno={page_number}")
    src = result.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')
    page_limit = soup.find('div', {"class":"page-counter"})
    Job_titles = soup.find_all('h3', {"class":"title"})
    Company_names = soup.find_all('a', {'class':"gtmJobListingPostedBy"})
    Locations = soup.find_all('li', {'class':"location"})
    Salary = soup.find_all('li',{"class": "salary"})
    #Job_skills = soup.find('strong').text
    #Job_skills = soup.find_all('div',{"class":"description"})
    

    for i in range(len(Job_titles)):
        
        job_title.append(Job_titles[i].text)
        links.append(Job_titles[i].find('a').attrs['href'])
        company_name.append(Company_names[i].text)
        location.append(Locations[i].text)
        salary.append(Salary[i].text)
    
    page_number += 1
    if(page_number >= 2):
        print("pages ended here")
        break 

for link in links: 
    url = "https://www.reed.co.uk/" + link
    result = requests.get(url)
    src = result.content 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')
    requirements = soup.find('span', {'itemprop':"description"}).find('ul')
    #print(requirements)
    skills_text = ""
    if not(requirements==None):
        for li in requirements.text.split(';'):
            #print(str(li))
            skills_text += str(li)
    #skills_text = skills_text[0:3]
    skills.append(skills_text.strip())

file_list = [job_title, company_name, location, salary, skills]
exported = zip_longest(*file_list)
```

Comment: for text in requirements.find('li'):
        skills_text += li.text + ', ' where li is define?

Comment: This one should be written this way instead: for text in requirements.find('li'): but still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace this section in your code with this:

```
if not(requirements==None):
    for li in requirements.find('li'):
        print(str(li))
        skills_text += str(li) + ', '
skills_text = skills_text[:-2]
skills.append(skills_text)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help it worked. Although, it did not extract all the requirements for some reason. I guess the problem is the way I defined requirements variable

Comment: HI Nir Elbaz,  I used the code as suggest and it worked but only extract the first line <li> for each job description. Do you have any idea why. I have never used web scraping before so I would really appreciate if you cloud help me learn and understand how to use web scraping

Comment: Try to do for li in requirements.text.split(';'):

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, just tried it but still getting only the first requirement of each job

Comment: I see all the requiemrnts, for exmaple ; Uncover and interpret trends from business data and other available data sources
Create data models to provide clear insights to guide our business strategy
Quickly understand and assimilate business processes
Understand how to optimize data retrieval and how to develop dashboards, reports and other visualizations for stakeholders
Support the development of a data-centric culture within RSM by providing user support, guidance, and training
Actively own strategic relationships with key stakeholders across the business,  etc..